# Derech Halimud in Mir Yeshiva

Tags: torah-study, yeshiva-school

What is the *derech halimud* in Mir Yeshiva (Jerusalem)? As far as I know it is not the *Brisker derech*. What commentaries or *chiddushim* are learned there?

Comment: Unclear what you mean; especially since the Mir is composed of multiple Chaburot each with its own "agenda".

Comment: Well I don't know so much about this issue. So there are different methods of learning in Mir with different groups? Like Chassidish and Litvish? I'm interested to know about different Litvish learning methods. One that I have read about (Wikipedia) is Brisk.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I don't understand what's unclear. Is it just a big Beis Medrash were people learn what they want? That sounds like an answer!

Comment: I just wanted to note that my close vote was for too broad, not for unclear.

Comment: @msh210 does he want a list of every sefer learned in Mir?  "What chiddushim are learned there"?  There are thousands of chiddushim learned there.  Every avreich in Kiryas Sefer who published a kuntress of his chaburas and sold it on the corner in Geula and now there's someone learning it in Mir? I think it's a pretty broad question.

Comment: @YEZ, I think the question was "what (sorts of) books of _chidushim_ are widely studied there" (e.g. _chidushe Hagranat_). If **all** (sorts of) books of _chidushim_ are widely studied there, then that's an answer.

Comment: @msh210 How many different sorts would you say there are? Unless the answer would accept "all of them" without any support (since to support your answer, I imagine you would have to bring an example of each), we are still talking about a very long list.

Comment: @YEZ, I dunno. But that's something to bear in mind when answering. I don't think the question's too broad. (I don't think it's a great question, mind you. [I](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/169303/voters) didn't upvote it. But I think it can be open.) Four others agreed with me (three reopen-voters and, by implication, the OP), so I reopened.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - it's not " big Beis Medrash were people learn what they want" - it's a collection of say 4 dozen Chaburos spread over about 6 buildings with each Chaburah learning it's own "agenda" with its own methods and favorite Seforim. (Numbers are pure guesses). It's like a beverage factory that produces 50 types of drinks, not like a park where 50 families are spending the afternoon doing what they please. (What you describe is the  Mir of 25 years ago, before R' Nosson Tzvi זצ"ל took over.)

Answer (score 10):

As per [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_yeshiva_(Jerusalem)#Chaburas) article, the Mir is composed of a multitude of study groups, called Chaburot.

> Each Chabura is subdivided by Shiur (class), with one Maggid Shiur (lecturer) teaching an average of 40 to 60 students.

As no two individuals are the same, each Maggid Shiur has his own style of learning and teaching. However, according to [this](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8#.D7.93.D7.A8.D7.9A_.D7.9C.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.93) article, **the Mir has a unique central Derech Halimud**:

> על אף ריבוי הרבנים והלומדים בישיבות מיר, ישנה דרך לימוד מרכזית, המוכרת כ"שיטת מיר". המייצגים המרכזיים של שיטה זו הם הרב נחום פרצוביץ וכיום חתנו הרב אשר אריאלי.
>
> **אחד המאפיינים של שיטה זו הוא, הדקדוק הרב בלשון רש"י, והוצאת גדרים למדניים מדיוקי לשונו.‏**

"Despite the multitude of teachers and student in the Mir, there is a common Derech HaLimid, know as *Shitas Mir*."

"The main representatives of this Derech are the late [Rav Nochum Partzovitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nochum_Partzovitz) זצ"ל and ילח"ט his son in law [Rav Asher Arieli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_Arieli) שליט"א.

**"One of the [main] characteristics of this Derech, is a careful analysis of Rashi's wording and deriving a scholarly framework based on the nuances in Rashi's wording."**

It's fair to assume that the [transcriptions of Reb Nochum's shiurim](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5#.D7.9B.D7.AA.D7.91.D7.99.D7.95), published by his students -  *Chidushei Reb Nochum, Shiurei Reb Nochem* and *Chazon Nochum*  - are popular Seforim.

A description of these publications, gives us some more insight into *Shitas Mir*:

> בספר צועד הרב פרצוביץ לפי שיטת בריסק, ומסביר את הגמרא לאור לשונה ולשון הראשונים, כשהוא משתדל לא להוסיף פרשנות עצמאית.

"Reb Nochum followed the *Shitas Brisk*; **each Gemara is explained based on [a careful analysis of] its wording and that of the Rishonim, without adding one's own explanations.**

Also see [here](http://rotter.name/kolot/prime/16674.php) for a long article in Hebrew describing each Chaborah - where it's located and what it learns.

Interestingly enough, the late Rosh Yeshiva had his own Derech Halimud "matching up the opinions of Rishonim from various places". This Derech Halimud did not become popular in the Mir. ([ibid](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8#.D7.93.D7.A8.D7.9A_.D7.9C.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.93))

> לרב נתן צבי פינקל הייתה שיטת לימוד ייחודית, של התאמת דעות הראשונים לשיטתם במקומות אחרים. שיטה לימוד זו לא נפוצה בישיבה.‏

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This was exactly what I was looking for.